# adb: CreateFileW 'null' failed: The system cannot find the specified file

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I installed Android Studio 3.0.1 in Windows 10 and it turns out that I can not launch any emulator, as much as you create these emulators, these are not displayed and I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I have verified that the ADB is not running and that other processes also listen to port 5037 as other users indicate. The strange thing isadb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed:

Comment: Please post the actual text of the error and not a screenshot. There are additional debug lines that you don't mention.

Comment: this is the log that shows android strudio when I try to Run: 22:38 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

22:38 adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (2)

22:38 * failed to start daemon

22:38 error: cannot connect to daemon

22:38 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Comment: An other thing that I discover is when I run an emulator, the log shows: Emulator: The system cannot find the specified file. like five times.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also appeared on my computer, but after reinstalling the Windows system and Android Studio, the problem is no longer there.