# Android Studio : adb unable to connect to local host 5037 CreateFileW nul system cannot file specified

Tags: android-studio, adb

I know this is an duplicate question and believe me I have read every thread there is on this post

1) [adb: CreateFileW 'null' failed: The system cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086541/adb-createfilew-null-failed-the-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file)

2) [Daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202232/daemon-not-running-starting-it-now-on-port-5037-cannot-open-nul-the-system)

3) [ddms: 'adb.exe,start-server' failed — run manually if necessary, Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137634/ddms-adb-exe-start-server-failed-run-manually-if-necessary-android-studio)

I have tried EVERYTHING!!!

a)Uninstalling android studio,its emulators,sdk and deleting every folder saying android in my system
from C:/Users/${HOME}/AddData/Local & Roaming to even C:/Windows/[All System Folders(No adb was found in these folders)},Program Data etc.

b)Uninstalling and Reinstalling Platform Tools from Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools after android studio reinstallation

c)Manually going to ${ANDROID_SDK_HOME}/platform-tools folder, opening cmd as administrator and running

->adb start-server[Gives Same Error As Above]

->adb kill-server[Unable to connect to target machine ip xxx.xx.xx connection actively refused]

->adb start-server[Same Error As My Question]

d)Tried to verify if any apps running on port 5037

netstat -aon | findstr 5037

nothing

My specs are[No new updates are available for any of the below specifications]

1)Android Studio 3.5.1

2)Platform Tools 29.0.4

3)gradle 5.4.1

4)Windows 10 64 bit

Also i have geny motion installed but with no adb the emulator is not recognized in the device list

I know this issue was posted atleast an year back but i hope some new light has been shed on the issue

plzz help thank u in advanced